# Delete all folders named XXX in folder YYY by DOS command

Tags: directory, dos

Under folder YYY, lots of subfolders with different names, I like to delete all folder name XXX, how?

I know `del /s YYY/XXX.*` but its for delete files, not folders

Comment: There may be files inside XXX, but delete anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line:

```
for /D %f in (XXX*) do rmdir %f /s
```

Comment: Once you're confident the command is doing what you want it to do, you can add a `/q` to invoke silent mode.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this via the CMD line.

```
RD /S /Q "Full Path of Folder"
```

Here is a link on how to do this: [Link1](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/55721-folder-delete-command-prompt.html)

Comment: This will only delete root, not what's under it